# In gdb, how to just continue print when full screen?

Tags: gdb, signals

I'm enabling printing some frequent signals (SIGPROF, for example) in gdb. When one screen of lines are filled, gdb prompts
---Type  to continue, or q  to quit---
Is there a way to just let it just continue without showing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible to use the `set height` command for that:

```
(gdb) help set height
Set number of lines in a page for GDB output pagination.
This affects the number of lines after which GDB will pause
its output and ask you whether to continue.
Setting this to "unlimited" or zero causes GDB never pause during output.
```

Alternatively, you can switch of printing of `SIGPROF` occurrences using `handle SIGPROF noprint`.